# Regex for non-title-casing with nordic chars (ÆØÅæøå)

Tags: regex, character-encoding

I am encountering some issues with a regex that should match all non-title-case strings. The problem is that it matches all sentences containing the nordic characters ÆØÅæøå (at least when I run it through https://www.regex101.com/).

```
\b([ÆØÅA-Z])([ÆØÅA-Z][ÆØÅA-Zæøåa-z]*)|\b([æøåa-z])([æøåa-zÆØÅA-Z]+)
```

It should match strings like:

```
"RØDOVRE"
```

It should NOT match strings like:

```
"Rødovre"
```

Comment: It's the `\b` that's not working the way you expect -- `ø` is treated as a non-word character (next to a word character) which lets the `\b` match in the middle of the string. What language are you targeting? This regex should work in .NET, for example.

Comment: Python is my target language. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to match single words one at a time, or are you trying to pick out individual words from a sentence or larger section of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this expression:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|^)([ÆØÅA-Z]+)(?:(?=\s)|$)
```

Here is a [Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eY4kQ8/1)